# Was Aristarchos' method to compute Earth-Sun distance ever rediscovered in medieval or modern times?

Tags: sun, moon

Ancient Greek astronomer Aristarchos who lived around 300 BC found a method to compute the Eart-Sun distance by applying geometry.

[In this video about the cosmic distance ladder](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7ne0GArfeMs), at 26:30, Terence Tao explains that Aristarchos was basically limited by nonexisting clock technology.
So he was not able to accurately measure the time difference between the time of (1/2 (new moon - fullmoon)) and time at which sun-moon distance was exactly at 90 degrees to the  intersection of earthorbit - moonorbit. See screenshots.

[image: Aristarchos 1]

[image: Aristachos 2]

Why was his method never refined in more modern times? Someone could have independently discovered the computation by a similar way of reasoning, but with better clocks.

Or *did* some European Astronomer else do this after mechanical clocks were invented, and it was just not accurate enough so they went for the transit-of-venus-method?

Comment: The video is very long and you might want to skip to 6:30 where the information presention starts.

Comment: you can see from the screenshots that the information is presented at 26:30